# How code AWS Lambda to report back to pipline about job done?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

Edit: changed lambda function and logs output, problem reminas :/

Have following lambda function as step in codepipeline:

```
import boto3
import json
import sys
import os
import pymysql
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

DB_HOST = os.environ['DB_HOST']
DB_USER = os.environ['DB_USER']
DB_PASS = os.environ['DB_PASS'], 
DB_PORT = int(os.environ['DB_PORT'])

codepipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')
cursorType = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor

try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host=DB_HOST, 
        user=DB_USER,
        password=DB_PASS, 
        port=DB_PORT,
     
    )
except pymysql.MySQLError as err:
    logger.error("Error: Could not connect to MySql db")
    logger.error(err)
    sys.exit()
    
logger.info("Success: Connected to MySql db")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        logger.info("Dropping db...")
        cursor.execute(f"drop database {DB_NAME}")
        logger.info("Creating db...")
        cursor.execute(f"create database {DB_NAME}")
        logger.info("Db created")
        connection.close()
        logger.info('Conection closed')
        job_id = event['CodePipeline.job']['id']
        logger.info("Job id `{job_id}`")
        response = codepipeline.put_job_success_result(jobId=job_id)
        logger.info(response)
    except Exception as err:
        logger.error(err)  
        response = codepipeline.put_job_failure_result(
            jobId=job_id, failureDetails={'message': message, 'type': 'JobFailed'}
        )
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
    }
```

Function log from function run:

```
START RequestId: 02e2f7cb-817d-4e49-90db-5b4cae5c9336 Version: $LATEST 
[INFO] 2020-09-23T07:38:34.515Z  Found credentials in environment variables. 
[INFO] 2020-09-23T07:38:34.598Z  Success: Connected to MySql db 
{'CodePipeline.job': {'id': '9a8b13ea-d4f8-4aea-8481-60db0b7b5b5d... snip} 
Dropping db 
Creating db 
Db created 
Conection closed 
[INFO] 2020-09-23T07:38:34.732Z 02e2f7cb-817d-4e49-90db-5b4cae5c9336 Job id 9a8b13ea-d4f8-4aea-8481-60db0b7b5b5d 
successfuly done 
END RequestId: 02e2f7cb-817d-4e49-90db-5b4cae5c9336 
REPORT RequestId: 02e2f7cb-817d-4e49-90db-5b4cae5c9336 Duration: 60060.17 ms Billed Duration: 60000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 76 MB Init Duration: 426.53 ms  
2020-09-23T07:39:34.660Z 02e2f7cb-817d-4e49-90db-5b4cae5c9336 Task timed out after 60.06 seconds
[INFO] 2020-09-23T07:39:35.55Z  Found credentials in environment variables. 
[INFO] 2020-09-23T07:39:35.94Z  Success: Connected to MySql db 
START RequestId: 02e2f7cb-817d-4e49-90db-5b4cae5c9336 Version: $LATEST 
{'CodePipeline.job': {'id': '9a8b13ea-d4f8-4aea-8481-60db0b7b5b5d',... snip} 
Dropping db 
Creating db 
Db created 
Conection closed 
[INFO] 2020-09-23T07:41:39.974Z 02e2f7cb-817d-4e49-90db-5b4cae5c9336 Job id 9a8b13ea-d4f8-4aea-8481-60db0b7b5b5d 
successfuly done 
END RequestId: 02e2f7cb-817d-4e49-90db-5b4cae5c9336 
REPORT RequestId: 02e2f7cb-817d-4e49-90db-5b4cae5c9336 Duration: 60060.32 ms Billed Duration: 60000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 30 MB  
2020-09-23T07:42:39.925Z 02e2f7cb-817d-4e49-90db-5b4cae5c9336 Task timed out after 60.06 seconds
```

How can I "force" lambda to report back to codepipeline that job is done either ok or not instead of just running in some kind of loop?

Lambda IAM role has policy attached like below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:Describe*",
                "ssm:Get*",
                "ssm:List*",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "codepipeline:PutJobSuccessResult",
                "codepipeline:PutJobFailureResult"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Help please as I can't find reason why lambda is not "letting know" back to pipeline about job status.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So  either create codepipline vpc endpoint or move lambda to private network... case solved :).